# Create fresh new BitmapMetadata for a newly created JpegXR encoded image in C#

Tags: c#, .net, metadata, wic, jpeg-xr

I am trying to create (encode) a Bitmap into a file - the format shall be JpegXR and I want metadata to be associated with it. WIC and it's counterparts in C# (.Net) do a great job but I fail to creating any kind of metadata object.

This is what I'm trying to do (wb is my image; w/o metadata it works):

```
WmpBitmapEncoder enc = new WmpBitmapEncoder
{
    UseCodecOptions = true,
    FrequencyOrder = true, // (progressive)
    QualityLevel = 1, // 1=lossless 255=worst
    HorizontalTileSlices = 0,
    VerticalTileSlices = 0,
    Lossless = true,
};

var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(wb);

var meta0 = bitmapFrame.CreateInPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter();
var meta1 = bitmapFrame.Metadata;
enc.Frames.Add(bitmapFrame);
BitmapMetadata meta2 = new BitmapMetadata("wdp");
enc.Metadata = meta2;

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(target, FileMode.Create))
{
    enc.Save(fileStream);
}
```

The result is: `meta0` `== null`, `meta1` also yields `null`

and the call to `new BitmapMetadata("")` throws an exception regardless of the string I provide: `ArgumentException` "Property cannot be found".

So how is one supposed to supply / create image metadata for images created from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

I got it somehow this way. However I don't understand the relations between format specific metadata ("wmphoto") and EXIF("exif") or XMP("xmp").

It's not possible to set the `enc.Metadata`-property to any of those instances.

```
                WmpBitmapEncoder enc = new WmpBitmapEncoder
                {
                    UseCodecOptions = true,
                    FrequencyOrder = true, // (progressive)
                    QualityLevel = 1, // 1=lossless 255=worst
                    HorizontalTileSlices = 0,
                    VerticalTileSlices = 0,
                    Lossless = true,
                    //Metadata = new BitmapMetadata("exif"), no no no
                    //Metadata = new BitmapMetadata("xmp"), no no no
                };
                //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
                BitmapMetadata bitmapMetadata =new BitmapMetadata("wmphoto");
                bitmapMetadata.ApplicationName = "ReEnCoder";
                bitmapMetadata.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif/{ushort=36867}", DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
                bitmapMetadata.Author = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(new []{"RibRob"});
                var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(wb, null, bitmapMetadata, null);

                enc.Frames.Add(bitmapFrame);
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(target, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    enc.Save(fileStream);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It creates just a very basic EXIF metadata (change date taken  and manufacturer, of course):

```
    static BitmapMetadata CreateBasicExif()
    {
        //see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

            BitmapMetadata jpgMetadata = new BitmapMetadata("jpg");
            jpgMetadata.DateTaken = new DateTime(2000,1,1).ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
            jpgMetadata.CameraManufacturer = "Panda";
            return jpgMetadata;
    }
```

It can be used with functions published here:
http://www.dustyfish.com/blog/writing-photo-metadata-using-windows-imaging-component